# Application crashes at certain point when run without debugger attached? c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, runtime-error, exe

I have a small application, it launches properly without debugger and all the features work except one which uses IronOcr (package from NuGet package manager). When I try to use this feature the program just closes.

When I launch this application from within visual studio, everything works fine. No errors and all features work. I get the same result if I run it and attach the debugger to it afterwards. However if I run the exe by launching the exe /bin/release and do not attach the debugger it crashes when I try to use the feature involving IronOcr.

I tested this on a virtual machine, same results with/without debugger. I then tested it on a different computer (fresh install of windows only having VS installed) it gave me this error if debugger is attached:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'IronOcr, Version=2021.2.1.0, >Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c2cbcea5ea3f6d8d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot >find the file specified

I've spent the last few days looking up a reason for this but I have not found one so far that fixes the issue.

What is confusing me the most is:

I assume the error that causes the program to close is the same error that causes it to give this error on the different PC. When I run it through VS it has no issues (it finds the file?) but running it from the exe it cannot find the file. I'm not moving the exe, just running it where it is in the bin/release.

I'm hoping this program will be able to run as a standalone exe.

I am still relatively new to c# and VS, the error may be glaringly obvious, or I may be using the wrong words causing me to not find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably a bit too late, but your problem certainly comes from the fact you're using the free licence of IronOCR. It seems that this one only works when  the debugger is attached.
If you catch the exception, you get that message:

> IronSoftware.Licenses.Exceptions.LicensingException: IronOcr must be
> licensed for deployment outside of the Visual Studio development
> environment. https://ironpdf.com/licensing

In my opinion this is too restrictive for proper evaluation, so I gave up trying to use it.

Comment: i put this project on hold a while ago, however that answer seems to answer every problem that i had, and makes sense thinking about it. Thanks! Will definitely help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure IronOcr.dll is exist at same directory as your executable file.

Try to execute your application from Bin/Debug and see if it runs ok or not.

Check to see if IronOcr.dll exist in Bin/Debug but does not exist in Bin/Release. if so then copy it from Bin/Debug to Bin/Release.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. Both contain IronOcr.dll and both still crash when launching from that directory. Could it be a bug or is it something I've missed do you know?

Comment: I'm affraid I can not think of another reason. It will help if you share some part of your code using IronOcr.dll via github. @TedDoi